# Android Animation Library?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-library

Are there any **FREE Android Animation Libraries** that we can use in our applications ?

The android built-in animations are very basic. I want something more fancy.

Comment: i use this lib for animating items in my view. it is relatively easy to use but it has one issue which you cant repeat animation and you need some coding to do to overcome this issue. https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching and digging, this is the final answer I got:

There isn't an available one. You need to write your animations.

Hope to see Android Animation Library sooon !

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen @wtsang02`s answer? If it does not fit your requirements, what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Did you create your own library?

Answer (score 9):

There is one out there now.

[NineOldAndroid](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids)

Comment: NineOldAndroid seems to be deprecated

Comment: Check this link for free libraries  -  https://android-arsenal.com/free

Answer (score 7):

There is an android library I created.

> https://github.com/2359media/AndroidAnimator

Its an animation library that aims to make android animations easier, allowing many complex animation effects to be achieved with one or two lines of code.

Comment: This is sweet... however few of then wont work. Nice job...

Answer (score 3):

Animation library  [Rebound](http://facebook.github.io/rebound/) seems to be promising and is used by facebook in their android app. I used nineolddroid too and it is really good too.

Answer (score 2):

So the most simple animations would be the ones like tween animation (Usually defined in the anim folder) you can find a lot of theese sorts through stackoverflow, the android samples folder etc.. there are all sorts of rotate translate and scale animations and combinations of them you can do on every view. combine that with a view flipper or something similar you can have pretty awsome view animations. i believe the one app on the market that shows this sorts of things and how far you can really go is the Pulse reader app,

I usually use theese when trying to hide/show views depending on state( scroll amount in a list, click on a button to slide in/fade in other views, make them dissapear/appear on touch on some view etc..). but in all these situations you need to figure out how you want to use them, connect things yourself. there is no easy way around this. most of the work is actually doing the connections not creating the actual animation.

Second thing i find really great which pushes view animations to a next level is the camera class used for 3d graphic transformations. this is a bit more complicated to use than the regular anims. there are a couple of really interesting projects using the camera class like:

[Coverflow](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/01/android-coverflow-widget.html)

[3d list](http://blogs.sonyericsson.com/wp/2010/05/20/android-tutorial-making-your-own-3d-list-part-1/)

also there are 2 java classes for 3d transformations which are a lot simpler to start with in the android samples projects.(have 3d in the names).

And for your question. no there isn't a specific library that will make really complex animations in 2 lines of code. you need to work it in there.

Comment: Is this a user profile ?

Comment: Did you read the public repository project names? CAAT is the project... there are sample projects, and the source of the library.

Comment: Do you mean that CAAT is an Android Animation Library? !!!

Comment: Canvas Advanced Animation Toolkit. what does that tell you?

Comment: Tells me that it is a .js library ! Do you agree?

Comment: oops. OK scratch that.. sorry. this is in a totally different direction.. ok so now to try to get myself out of this. i am editing my answer with relevant info for your question.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. Although it isn't helping a lot, but I appreciated it. Hope to see an Android Animation Archive Website soon